# Do grandchildren get property share if their father and grandfather is dead?

Tags: inheritance

My grandfather has a shop . He died at a young age.  He has 3 sons and 2 daughters . In his 3 sons , one is my father . Now my father also passed away . Will I get share in my grandfather's property ?

Comment: Did the grandfather pass away before the father?

Comment: There are two possible situation in any case you can only inherit based on your share of your father's share and supposed property. In that your father died before his father you may get a share from your grandfather's shop else it depends whether your father and his siblings left the business ongoing after their father's death as it is possible that some of them have no more shares in it.

Comment: Yes, grandfather passed away when my father was 17 and my father passed away at the age of 50